# Delay between setNeedsDisplay() and call of redraw() function

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, drawrect

I am writing an app that fetches steps data from HealthKit and displays statistics on the screen. I have a viewcontoller with a delegate protocol function:

```
func userValueForHistogramView(sender: HistogramView) -> CGFloat? {
        return userValue
    }
```

Where userValue is:

```
var userValue : CGFloat = 1000 {
    didSet{
        println("DidSet")
        histogramView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

The drawRect function on HistogramView looks like this:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var value = dataSource?.userValueForHistogramView(self)
        println("\(value)")
    }
```

I initiate an update of a userValue through the function:

```
func startRefreshByGettingUserValue()
```

When the function is simply:

```
func startRefreshByGettingUserValue(){
        userValue = 1500;
}
```

I get an instantaneous log message "DidSet" followed by the value of userValue from redrawRect().

Now, when I change the function to :

```
func startRefreshByGettingUserValue(){
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let today = NSDate()

        let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: today)

        let startDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)

        let endDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay,
            value: 1, toDate: startDate!, options: NSCalendarOptions(0))

        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, options: .StrictStartDate)

        let sampleQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount), quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .CumulativeSum)
            { (sampleQuery, results, error ) -> Void in

                if let quantity = results?.sumQuantity(){
                    self.userValue = CGFloat(quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit()) )

                }
        }
        HKStore.executeQuery(sampleQuery)
}
```

I get instantaneous "DidSet" message in the log, but the actual value comes 10 seconds later (i.e. drawRect is lagged).

Why does this happen? And how to make it work without a delay ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKStatisticsQuery_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKStatisticsQuery/initWithQuantityType:quantitySamplePredicate:options:completionHandler:):

> Queries run on an anonymous background queue. As soon as the query is
>   complete, the results handler is executed on the same background queue
>   (but not necessarily on the same thread). You typically dispatch these
>   results to the main queue to update the user interface.

The closure you passing in as the completion handler runs asynchronously, so the `userValue` is set and `setNeedsDisplay()` called in background. That's is not good.

UIKit APIs should be called on the main thread.

An easy fix would be:

```
var userValue : CGFloat = 1000 {
    didSet{
        println("DidSet")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            histogramView.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}
```